# C++ for_each_adjacent

Tags: c++, algorithm, template-meta-programming, c++17

I was watching a C++ Talk and he showed some code for a basic for_each_adjacent.
I took the base concept and improved it a little bit, I am wondering if i could have any feedback. It automatically deduces the amount of parameters.

My main concern is the remainder. I am not sure to pass in a epilogue function for the remaining variables, or a pointer to remaining variables. If i use an epilogue function, I can foresee some issues with a vectors, because its size can change a run time. Ultimately that would force the epilogue to have the same parameter count as the lambda, and which some of the values would be null, but I would have to set them to 0 and it could be a headache to tell if they are really 0 or supposed to be null? Hopefully that makes sense. Anyways, here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aghnpqkvdCg) which started the whole thing if your curious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <optional>

namespace detail
{
    template<class Function, class Iterator, unsigned... IntegerSequence>
    auto apply(Function f, Iterator first, std::integer_sequence<unsigned, IntegerSequence...>)
    {
        return f(*std::next(first, IntegerSequence)...);
    }
    template<typename F>
    struct arg_count : arg_count<decltype(&F::operator())> {};

    template<typename F,typename Return,typename... Args>
    struct arg_count<Return(F::*)(Args...)const>
    {
        static const unsigned value = sizeof...(Args);
    };

    template<typename F>
    constexpr const unsigned arg_count_v = arg_count<F>::value;
}


//Returns a pointer to the remainder values or the end or nullptr
template<class Iterator,class Function>
auto for_each_adjacent(Iterator begin,Iterator end,Function func)
    -> std::optional<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer>
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    const value_type length = std::distance(begin,end);
    const std::ptrdiff_t remainder = length % detail::arg_count_v<Function>;

    for (auto d = length; d >= detail::arg_count_v<Function>; d -= detail::arg_count_v<Function>)
        detail::apply(func,(end - d),std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned,detail::arg_count_v<Function>>());

    return (remainder) ? std::make_optional(end - remainder) : std::nullopt;
}


int main()
{
    std::array<int,256> test_array{};
    std::iota(test_array.begin(),test_array.end(),0);

    std::optional<int*> leftover_values = for_each_adjacent(test_array.begin(),test_array.end(),[](int a,int b,int c) {
        std::cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
    });

    std::cout << leftover_values.value()[0]; // 255;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this for any other examples, e.g. a `std::list<std::string>`? The compiler should have some things to tell you for that one...

Answer (score 4):

```
    template<class Function, class Iterator, unsigned... IntegerSequence>
    auto apply(Function f, Iterator first, std::integer_sequence<unsigned, IntegerSequence...>)
    {
        return f(*std::next(first, IntegerSequence)...);
    }
```

The `Iterator` has the requirements of a [forward iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) (dereferenceable, forward traversal, multipass).  At the very least, document the iterator type. Also, you should check to make sure the iterator meets the requirements.

The sequence type is too narrow and doesn't support a commonly used sequence like `std::index_sequence`.

The sequence helpers are defined in `<utility>`. Don't rely on latent dependencies from other includes, if you reference it, you should include it.

```
#include <cstddef>       // std::ptrdiff_t
#include <iterator>      // std::iterator_traits, std::next, std::distance
#include <type_traits>   // std::is_base_of
#include <optional>
#include <utility>       // std::make_integer_sequence
/* ... */

    template<class Function, class ForwardIterator, class Index, Index... Indices>
    auto apply(Function f, ForwardIterator first, std::integer_sequence<Index, Indices...>)
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<std::forward_iterator_tag,
                typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::iterator_category
            >::value, "");
        return f(*std::next(first, Indices)...);
    }
```

---

```
    template<typename F>
    constexpr const unsigned arg_count_v = arg_count<F>::value;
```

Programmers typically refer to the number of arguments or operands a function or operation takes as the [Arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity).

What is the arity of `[](auto...){}`? What is the arity of `[](){}` and how does that interact with any subsequent divisions?

Try to be consistent with your naming.  While `F` is commonly `Function`, you kinda bounce between the two.  Pick one and be consistent.

---

```
//Returns a pointer to the remainder values or the end or nullptr
template<class Iterator,class Function>
auto for_each_adjacent(Iterator begin,Iterator end,Function func)
-> std::optional<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer>
```

Adjacents work like a sliding window, where each subsequent window starts at an offset of 1 from the first element in the previous window, e.g.

$$
[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], ...
$$

The behavior you have implemented is a window over chunk sizes, incrementing from the last element in the previous window instead of the first, e.g.

$$
[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], ...
$$

and some remainder less than the the length.  Consider renaming this function to a name that better represents its action, (`for_each_chunked`?).

Reading your comment, why not just return `std::optional<Iterator>` or the `Iterator` itself? After the calls, `begin` will always point to the first element in the remaining chunk or `end`.  The user can check if the returned iterator is at `end`.

---

```
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    const value_type length = std::distance(begin,end);
```

This doesn't make sense. `Iterator::value_type` is the type of the values that can be obtained by dereferencing the iterator.  `std::list<std::string>::iterator::value_type` is `std::string`.  Just use `auto` and let `std::distance` provide the correct type (`iterator::difference_type`, or `std::ptrdiff_t`).

```
    const auto length = std::distance(begin, end);
```

---

```
    const std::ptrdiff_t remainder = length % detail::arg_count_v<Function>;
    for (auto d = length; d >= detail::arg_count_v<Function>; d -= detail::arg_count_v<Function>)
        detail::apply(func,(end - d),std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned,detail::arg_count_v<Function>>());

return (remainder) ? std::make_optional(end - remainder) : std::nullopt;
```

Instead of trying to figure out if their are enough elements remaining to call a function by arity, just calculate the number of chunks you are going to call `f` with.  Integral division has the nice property of truncating the remainder.

```
    auto chunks = length / detail::arg_count_v<Function>;
```

If you really want the remainder

```
    auto [chunks, remainder] = std::div(length, detail::arg_count_v<Function>);
```

Then you just loop on that count.

```
    constexpr auto indices = std::make_index_sequence<detail::arg_count_v<Function>{};

    while (chunks--) {
        detail::apply(func, begin, indices);
        std::advance(begin, detail::arg_count_v<Function>);
    }

    return begin;
```

An added benefit it that you can keep supporting [forward iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) (`std::advance`) instead of elevating the requirement to [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) (`end - d`, `end-remainder`).

---

> I am not sure to pass in a epilogue function for the remaining variables

Does your use-case require you to have the entire range consumed by functions?  Let the caller decide what to do and just return an iterator.

Comment: Actually, `std::distance` return type is `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type`, which by default is `std::ptrdiff_t`, not `std::size_t`. // `end - d` requires `RandomAccessIterator`, not just `BidirectionalIterator`. // `for_each_adjacent`s return type is declared as `std::optional<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer>`, but the actual returned type is `std::optional<Iterator>`. (You mention this one as a possible improvement, but not the very likely type mismatch in the current code.)

Answer (score 4):

Your `arg_count_v` is trying to solve one of the [perennial impossibilities of C++](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/12/perennial-impossibilities/). What is the "arg count" (or *arity*, as Snowhawk rightly says) of the lambda

```
[](auto&&... xs) -> int { return sizeof...(xs); }
```

? Until you can answer that, you shouldn't write anything that depends on the arity of one of its arguments.

Also notice that `&F::operator()` doesn't necessarily exist; for example if `F` is a pointer-to-function type.

---

```
//Returns a pointer to the remainder values or the end or nullptr
```

But why?! Why would you make a generic algorithm that returns a *pointer*, when you have *iterators* conveniently passed in specifically for you to use?

Let's fix that and also fix the "arity" issue at the same time. We'll force the user to pass in their intended arity as a (non-deducible) template parameter. Since this parameter is non-deducible, it must come first.

Also, let's use the traditional names `first` and `last`, rather than `begin` and `end`. It's not a big deal, but it might help the reader's comprehension, because `begin` and `end` are also the names of functions
in `namespace std`, whereas `first` and `last` are the traditional names for range-based algorithms like this one.

```
template<size_t Arity, class Iterator, class Function>
Iterator for_each_adjacent(Iterator first, Iterator last, Function func)
{
    static_assert(Arity >= 1);
    using Indices = std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, Arity>;

    auto length = std::distance(first, last);
    auto remainder = length % Arity;

    for (auto d = length; d >= Arity; d -= Arity) {
        detail::apply(func, (last - d), Indices());
    }
    return last - remainder;
}
```

---

I removed the unused `value_type` typedef (well, it was used, but only in a place where `auto` should have been used, and actually using `value_type` there caused a bug, as Snowhawk pointed out). I also factored out `Indices` into a local typedef, for readability; but in a setting with longer line-lengths you might just inline it.

As Snowhawk notes, you should be using `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` instead of your weird `integer_sequence<unsigned,...>` business.

---

So far so good. But we can do much better, right?  Your current algorithm works only on *random-access* iterators. Let's make it work on *any* kind of iterator, by getting rid of the math.

```
template<size_t Arity, class Iterator, class Function>
Iterator for_each_adjacent(Iterator first, Iterator last, Function func)
{
    static_assert(Arity >= 1);
    using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<Arity>;

    while (true) {
        auto cur = first;
        for (size_t countdown = Arity; countdown != 0; --countdown) {
            if (cur == last) {
                return first;
            }
            ++cur;
        }
        detail::apply(func, first, Indices());
        std::advance(first, Arity);
    }
}
```

And then we need to adjust `detail::apply` a little bit:

```
template<class Function, class Iterator, size_t... Is>
auto apply(Function& f, Iterator first, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return f(*std::next(first, Is)...);
}
```

Notice that we must take `Function` by reference in this helper function, to avoid making a *copy* of it. The lambda passed in by our caller might not be copyable.

Actually, I strongly recommend taking `const Function&` in both signatures. But I recognize that the STL doesn't do that, for historical reasons.

---

The last change I would make is to eliminate the quadratic behavior in `apply`. `f(*std::next(first, Is)...)` computes `std::next(first, 1)`, `std::next(first, 2)`, `std::next(first, 3)`, and so on, doing the same increments over and over. We'd like to compute and save all our function arguments just *once*. So let's do that.

```
template<class Function, class Iterator, size_t... Is>
auto apply(Function& f, Iterator first, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    Iterator args[] = {
        (void(Is), first++) ...
    };
    return f(args[Is]...);
}
```

We could make this a little more efficient by thinking about how to use `++first` instead of `first++` here. (Hint: Pass in `std::make_index_sequence<Arity-1>()`!)

Notice that I'm casting `Is` to `void` here. This is a common trick among library implementors to defend against user-defined overloads of `operator,`:

```
void operator,(size_t, std::vector<MyWidget>::iterator) {
    puts("Hijacked!");
}
```

Overloads of `operator,` are basically never this malicious in the wild, but I recommend always adding the six extra characters `void()` because it's such a cheap price to pay for eliminating a whole class of really crazy bugs.